# Using CanCan to limit view on index page to user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, devise, indexing, cancan

I am utilizing Devise and Cancan for a rails 3.2.6 application. In the application, I allow users to create a document with some information gathered in a form. I then want to allow the user to list on a Document index page at localhost:3000/users/1/documents only their documents, which this is working. What isn't working, is I am trying to limit the user from being able to see everyone else's documents by replacing the /users/:id/documents with another number.

I am using cancan and have tried both

can :index, Document, :user_id => user.id
 can :read, Document, :user_id => user.id

and then on the Document controller index method

```
if can? :read, Document
 @documents = @user.documents
else
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

also tried with `:index` as well...but this isn't working. I am also using `load_and_authorize_resource`..

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

I will say, cancan is working for my user management and users controller for an admin to create, list and edit users, so I know cancan is working in general. It is also working for updating and deleting a users documents. It is just the index function not working.

```
class Ability 

include CanCan::Ability 

  def initialize(user) 

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in) 
    if user.id 
      if user.has_role? :user 
        can :create, Document 
        can :read, Document, :user_id => user.id 
        can :update, Document, :user_id => user.id 
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that non-logged in users, as well as users whose `user.id` isn't the same as the Document's `user_id` (document owner) don't have permission to read all Documents.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(account)

    user ||= User.new  #non-logged-in user

    # logged in users
    if user.id and user.has_role?(:user)

      #content owners
      can :manage, Document, :user_id => user.id

      #other logged-in users
      can [:show, :create], Document

    end

  end
end
```

Be careful you don't have any line like `can :read, :all` or `can :read, Document` most likely you are giving the permission somewhere if you said cancan is working already.

Comment: I added   `if can? :read, Documents
    @documents = @user.documents
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end `  to documents controller and my ability.rb has `class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.id
      
    
    if user.has_role? :user
      can :create, Document
      
     can :read, Document, :user_id => user.id
      
      can :update, Document, :user_id => user.id
     
      end
    end
  end
end ` and it is still not working...what am I missing?

Comment: sorry.new to posting here...my formatting needs work :) Anyways, CanCan is working where I can't edit or update a document that I don't own...It is just not working in which I don't want the user to be able to list any documents that dont belong to them.

Comment: edit your original comment with your code so we can get a better look at whats going wrong.

alternatively, you could actually just control the logic inside your view, but I don't think that's what you were going for.

Comment: No..I wha hoping to handle outside the view

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should write in your ability class

```
def initialize(user)
  can :manage, Document do |document|
    document.user == user
  end  
end
```

This will check whether document belongs to logged in user or not. If yes can will return true otherwise false.

For more details on how to handle complex authorization with block,

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks

Comment: made the change and then `if can? :manage, Document
    @documents = @user.documents
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end ` same problem ..I still can log in as userid 1 and list documents for user id 2

Comment: have you updated your code in ability class? if no, pls update that one first, as well add load_and_authorize_resource to your controller. Accessing any document that is not belongs to user should though an exception

Comment: In your controller code, instead of checking the user credential on Document model {if can? :manage, Document}, which will be false always since you have not defined it in ability; you should write directly 
     **@documents = @user.documents**. Try 
     **@documents = Document.all**; should through an exception